# Replace using Date.now() inside a reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Documentation said i should avoid state mutation by using new Date, etc inside reducers. Help me please with advice how should it be done.

Action:

```
const RECEIVE_PRICES = 'RECEIVE_PRICES';

function receivePrices(prices) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_PRICES,
    receivedAt: Date.now(),
    prices,
  };
}
```

REDUCER:

```
 ...
 case RECEIVE_PRICES: {
      let { prices } = action;

      prices = prices.map((p) => {
        const baseQuote = p.symbol.split('/');
        return { ...p, baseCurrency: baseQuote[0], quoteCurrency: baseQuote[1] };
      });

      prices.sort(
        (a, b) => new Date(a.timestamp).getTime() - new Date(b.timestamp).getTime(),
      );

      return {
        ...state,
        prices,
        pricesLoading: false,
        pricesError: null,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

Comment: Moving all the logic to a middleware is a good idea. In this specific example, you can technically move the logic to the action creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Redux, all side-effects (not just api calls) should take place inside Action Creators. You should move this logic into the action creator and have the caller pass the necessary parameters.